# Finding out when user has swiped the slider till end

Tags: swiper.js

I am making a mobile app in which i have to keep a feature of swipe to delete. Since i have used swiper dangerous swiper in my app for some other purpose, i thought to use the same for swipe to delete feature. Below is the code i wrote

```
for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){$(".dashboard").append("<div class='swiper-container eachSwiper'><div class='swiper-wrapper'><div class='swiper-slide'><span><img src='img/Customer.png'/></span>hello</span><br>there</span></div></div></div>");
                var inSwiper = "swiper"+i;

            var options = {
                onTransitionEnd : function(inSwiper){
                    console.log("its removed");
                }
            }
                 inSwiper = new Swiper('.eachSwiper',options);}
```

i am creating new swiper-container class for every loop run. and only swiper-slide in that. Its working fine. But the problem is the onTransitionEnd function is executing even if i slide a little bit. Can someone help me out in figuring out on how to write a condition when the user swipes it till the end. I checked the api,but could'nt find any thing other than onTransitionEnd.
Thanks

Answer (score 7):

There is [`reachEnd`](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#event-reachEnd) Event that needs to bind so when ever swiper reach to end that will get triggered.

Below is the example:

```
swiper.on('reachEnd', function(){
   console.log("reach to End");
});
```

For more in detail about swiper events and methods below is the documentation.

https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#events

Answer (score 4):

TransitionEnd is not what you're looking for. Transition end is when the animation that transition the page forwards or backwards stop.

What you're looking for is `isEnd` and then call it via the callback slideChangeEnd

```
mySwiper.on('slideChangeEnd', function () {
    if (mySwiper.isEnd) {
            console.log("end is reached");
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use events `reachEnd` `fromEdge` and `fromEdge`

```
swiper.on('reachEnd', function() {
    var swjsNext = document.querySelector('.swiper-button-next');
    swjsNext.style.display = 'none'; 
});

swiper.on('reachBeginning', function() {
    var swjsPrev = document.querySelector('.swiper-button-prev');
    swjsPrev.style.display = 'none'; 
});

swiper.on('fromEdge', function() {
    var swjsNext = document.querySelector('.swiper-button-next');
    swjsNext.style.display = 'flex';
    var swjsPrev = document.querySelector('.swiper-button-prev');
    swjsPrev.style.display = 'flex';    
});
```